# Simulation of Central Limiting Theorem (CLT)

Tags: python, statistics, simulation

The following is the simulation of [Central Limiting Theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiV6blF1crE&t=743s) from Statistics:

```
class MyRandom:
    m = 4294967296;# modulus
    a = 1664525; # multiplier
    c = 1013904223; # increment
    seed = 1; #initial seed
    def NextInt(self):
        self.seed = (((self.a * self.seed + self.c) % self.m));
        return self.seed;

    def NextIntMm(self, mins, maxs):
        temp = self.NextInt();
        ddd = float(temp) / float(self.m);
        returns =  int((maxs - mins) * ddd + mins);
        return returns;

    def NextDouble(self):
        temp = self.NextInt();
        return float(temp) / float(self.m);

    def NextDoubleMm(self, mins, maxs):
        temp = self.NextInt();
        fraction = float(temp) / float(self.m);
        return (maxs - mins) * fraction + mins;

#################################################################
N = 999999;            
r = MyRandom();
population = [];
population_sum = 0;

for i in range(0, N):
    x = r.NextDouble();
    population.append(x);
    population_sum = population_sum + x;

population_mean = population_sum / len(population);

print("Population mean = ", population_mean);

##################################################################
rnd_num_count = 30;
sample_size = 12;
sample_means = [];
sum_of_sample_mean = 0;

for i in range(0, rnd_num_count):
    sums = 0;
    for j in range(0, sample_size):
        index = r.NextIntMm(0, N - 1);
        element = population[index];
        sums = sums + element;

sample_mean = sums / sample_size;
sum_of_sample_mean = sum_of_sample_mean + sample_mean;
sample_means.append(sample_mean);

print("Mean of sample mean = ", sum_of_sample_mean/ len(sample_means));
```

Here, Normal Distribution of population is used.

Can you review this and point out any possible improvement needed?

N.B. Defining a random number generator is part of the requirement.

Comment: You are aware of the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module in the standard library, right? If so, consider adding the [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] tag.

Comment: I guess you have an indentation error in your second example, the second-to-last block should probably under the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @Graipher, No, my program is running smoothly in Spyder.

Comment: That may be the case, but it will probably not do the right thing because `sample_means` would contain only the last sample mean and `sums` will be reset every loop iteration without being used, so `sample_mean` will only use the `sums` from the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are implementing your own random number generator, I would stick to the interface defined in the standard library module `random`. You could have a `random`, a `uniform`, a `randint` (or `randrange` if it is inclusive on the end) and a `choices` method.

Your class should probably also allow setting the seed on creation.

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends not using trailing `;` and using `lower_case` both for variables as well as functions/methods.

Even in Python 2 (which you should no longer use), if either the numerator or the divisor is a `float`, the result is also a `float` with the division operator `/`, so you only need to cast one of them. In Python 3 `/` is always float division and `//` is always integer division, so no need for the casts to `float`.

You should always add a [`dosctring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your code explaining how to use it.

For `range`, the start is implicitly `0`. Also `_` is conventionally used for unused loop variables.

Wrap the code that uses your class in a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script without it running.

```
class Random:
    """A pseudo-random number generator using a LCG."""
    m = 4294967296 # modulus
    a = 1664525    # multiplier
    c = 1013904223 # increment

    def __init__(self, seed=1):
        """Initialize the pseudo-random number generator with a seed (default: 1)."""
        self.state = seed

    def randint(self, a=None, b=None):
        """Return either a random integer between `0` and `self.m`
        or between `a` and `b` (exclusive?)."""
        if a is None and b is None:
            self.state = (self.a * self.state + self.c) % self.m
            return self.state
        elif a is not None:
            if b is not None:
                return int(self.uniform(a, b))
            else:
                return int(self.uniform(0, a))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Need to also set `a` if you set `b`.")

    def random(self):
        """Return a random float between 0 and 1 (exclusive?)."""
        return float(self.randint()) / self.m

    def uniform(self, a, b):
        """Return a random float between `a` and `b` (exclusive?)."""
        return (b - a) * self.random() + a

    def choices(self, population, k=1):
        """Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement."""
        n = len(population)
        return [population[self.randint(n - 1)] for _ in range(k)]
```

The usage of this is similar to your code, just with renamed methods.

You can also greatly shorten your examples using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and a utility function `mean`:

```
random = Random()

def mean(x):
    return float(sum(x)) / len(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 999999   
    population = [random.random() for _ in range(N)]
    print("Population mean = ", mean(population))

    rnd_num_count = 30
    sample_size = 12
    sample_means = [mean(random.choices(population, k=sample_size))
                    for _ in range(rnd_num_count)]
    print("Mean of sample mean = ", mean(sample_means))
```

This script has the advantage that you can easily test it with the standard library `random` module by replacing the line `random = Random()` with `import random`. This way you can see if your class produces random numbers somewhat correctly.

---

If implementing so many different random functions gets tedious, you can also subclass `random.Random`:

> Class `Random` can also be subclassed if you want to use a different
>   basic generator of your own devising: in that case, override the
>   following methods:  `random()`, `seed()`, `getstate()`, and `setstate()`.
>   Optionally, implement a `getrandbits()` method so that `randrange()` can
>   cover arbitrarily large ranges.

This of course means that you are using the standard library and not your own implementations as much. In that case you probably also want to use `statistics.mean`.